# Count number of digits in one field

Tags: oracle-sqlcl

I'm trying to come up with a code that would count the number of digits in one field.
in this case it's passports I want to make sure they have valid digits and characters.

```
select  p.passport_nbr,
        CASE WHEN Number = 0 THEN 1
               ELSE FLOOR(LOG10(ABS(p.passport_nbr))) + 1 AS NDigits
```

,
is there a different code I can use.
I use oracle sql

Comment: Do you really need to count digits or you need to decide if the value matching pattern? Because for pattern matching the best solution is REGEXP_LIKE https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19

Comment: You shouldn't use `Number` as a fieldname - it's an Oracle [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm) - in principle you should not use reserved words as identifiers - it can lead to all sorts of potential problems (legibility, portability, debugging...) - **avoid**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume passport_nbr is a number type. Just convert it to a string and check the length:

```
select passport_nbr, length(to_char(passport_nbr)) from t;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IAvIwUk-)